# WordPress plugin or online service for monitoring the email for working properly

Tags: gratis, email, monitoring, wordpress

I have a WordPress website with a contact form 7 form for collecting the orders.

Some time for problems in the server the email service stops working and for some times the filled information of form is not sent to the admin by email.

How can I be notified by email quickly when the email is not working?

Is there any free and automatic method for being notified when the filled forms are not emailed?

[Here](http://www.websitepulse.com/services/email.monitoring.php) is some paid monitoring service. but I am looking for a free method.